# capture returned functions in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following piece of code as follows:

```
function(staticPath) {
    console.log('static Path = ' +staticPath);
    return function(data, response) {

        console.log('data = ' +data);
        console.log('response = ' +response);
        var readStream;
        // Fix so routes to /home and /home.html both work.
        data = data.replace(/^(\/home)(.html)?$/i, '$1.html');
        data = '.' + staticPath + data;
        fs.stat(data, function(error, stats) {
            if (error || stats.isDirectory()) {
                return exports.send404(response);
            }
            readStream = fs.createReadStream(data);
            return readStream.pipe(response);
        });
    }
}
```

This function basically parses the path to a HTML file and displays the contents of the file.

I am not able to understand how to call this method from outside.

I am calling it as follows:

```
staticFile("D:\\Node Applications\\public\\home.html")
```

I can capture it inside a variable `innerFunc` and i can call the inner function as `innerFunc(response)` where *response* is *http's serverResponse* of which i have the reference with me but i am not sure how can i pass the `data` param.

I am not understanding what is happening behind the scenes. Can anyone explain ? Do we encounter such kind of code often in javascript ?

**EDIT**:
To make things clear:
There is another method as follows:

```
function(data, response) {
    response.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    });
    response.end(JSON.stringify(data));
}
```

which i call from my node server logic as follows:

```
http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    // A parsed url to work with in case there are parameters
    var _url;
    // In case the client uses lower case for methods.
    req.method = req.method.toUpperCase();
    console.log(req.method + ' ' + req.url);

    if (req.method !== 'GET') {
        res.writeHead(501, {
            'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
        });
        return res.end(req.method + ' is not implemented by this server.');
    }
    if (_url is something like //localhost:1337/employees) {
            //call employee service which returns *data*.
            // send the data with a 200 status code
            return responder.sendJson(data, res);
        });
    } else {
        // try to send the static file
        /*res.writeHead(200);
        res.end('static file maybe');*/
        console.log('Inside else');
        var staticInner = responder.staticFile("D:\\Node Applications\\public\\home.html");
        staticInner(res);
    }

    // res.end('The current time is ' + Date.now())
}).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
```

As one can see there is no *data* variable to pass to the *innerFunc* hence, got confused.

Comment: Do you understand what is that function supposed to do? If you don't know how to _pass_ `data` (I think you mean you don't know what is `data`, because you would pass it as `innerFunc(data, response)`), I'd say you don't know what that function does. It would be good to know that. Also, are you expecting to get as result this: `return readStream.pipe(response)`, or something at all?

Comment: You are right. I have edited my question and as you can see i don't have the 'data' variable to pass it to the function. Initially, i thought i might be missing some understanding but it seems that the data variable is what i need to pass it to the function.

Can you explain what could be the reason here to return a function from a function ? For what all instances would this be required ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the "innerFunc", it seems like `data` is some string that, being concatenated with `staticPath`, forms a path to a file. As we can see, that path is tested with `fs.stat`. Maybe the client is supposed to send some custom data? At any rate, `data` seems to be a pretty bad name for a variable like that.

It seems like what that function is trying to do is to send a file as response? What `staticPath` is supposed to be is a path relative to the Javascript file where this code is, because it is concatenated like this:

```
data = '.' + staticPath + data;
```

That would end in something like `./some/path/index.html`. `staticPath`'s value would be `/some/path` and `data`'s value would be `index.html`. So if your JS file is in `/home/foo/node/index.js`, the file that the "innerFunc" will try to find would be in `/home/foo/node/some/path/index.html`.

If you pass `"D:\\Node Applications\\public\\home.html"` to `staticFile()` as you're doing, you would get something like `.D:\\Node Applications\\public\\home.htmlindex.html` which is clearly an invalid file.

*To answer what's the point of a function returning a function*

In this case, as mgouault said, it makes no sense at all to do that. Maybe the programmer had something in mind but changed it while programming this and the function ended up like that (it sometimes happen).

Answer (score 0):

Your functions (ex: `function(staticPath)`) should either have a name or be stored in a variable to be able to call them. So I will guess that you are storing all this code in the variable `staticFile`.

Then when you call it with a parameter: `staticFile("D:\\Node Applications\\public\\home.html")` it returns a function (`return function(data, response) {...}`).

Now that you have this inner function you can call it with `data` and `response`:

```
var innerFunc = staticFile("D:\\Node Applications\\public\\home.html");
innerFunc(data, response);
```

Which will responds using your variable `response` (I guess).

A function returning a function is frequent in javascript especially when using closures for certains purposes, but in this case it's not really useful.